# How do you install configuration profiles with iPhone Configuration Utility after Lion upgrade

Tags: iphone, ipad, enterprise

Since updating to Lion I can't install configuration profiles with the iPhone Configuration Utility on iPads etc for enterprise deployment. I can still however install apps. Problem is only with the configuration profiles. The Install button appears but it just doesn't do the install. This was fine before Lion. And I am using iPhone Configuration Utility 3.4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple Enterprise Support just figured this out for me.

Clean install of app.
Go to user directory/Library/preferences/iPhoneConfigurationUtility

go to preferences associated with iPhoneConfigurationUtility com.apple.iPhoneConfigurationUtility etc.
You will see plists.

Delete them.

Restart or reinstall.

Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I faced with similar problem when had tried to instal profile to my iPhone. But your question helped me find a solution, because you mention it has worked before Lion upgrade and I found that is access rights issue in Lion.

The workaround is:

1. Enable root account following by this instruction: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1528
2. Login as root
3. Start iPhone Configuration Utility and enjoy! It would works fine.

And I suggest turn off root account when you're done.

Comment: That worked fine. Then after I log in again I'm back to the same problem. I have checked to make sure root user is still enabled. Any suggestions? When I click "Install" for a configuration profile, nothing happens. iPad is connected via USB and I see it in the Utility.

Comment: If I try to log in as root it won't let me even though I set the root password as well.